# Issue with Adding Space Between Icon and Text in NSAttributedString

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add an icon into a text using NSAttributedString. I'm using a function called addIconToText, but I'm having trouble creating a space between the text and the icon. The icon and the text appear to be adjacent without any separation.

Here is the addIconToText function I'm using:

```
func addIconToText(text: String, icon: String, bounds: CGRect, font: UIFont, textColor: UIColor, underlineText: Bool = false) {
       let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
       let range = (text as NSString).range(of: text)
       attributedText.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: textColor, range: range)
       attributedText.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: range)
       if underlineText {
           attributedText.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: range)
       }
       let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
       attachment.image = UIImage(named: icon)
       attachment.bounds = bounds
       let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
       attributedText.insert(attachmentString, at: range.location)
       self.attributedText = attributedText
   }
   
private func setupDescription() {
   let font = UIFont.regularDMSans(of: MixerReviewConstants.descriptionFontSize)
   let bounds = CGRect(x: 3, y: -3, width: 16, height: 16)
   lblDescription.addIconToText(text: "Please Rate",
                                icon: "icon_dark",
                                bounds: bounds,
                                font: font,
                                textColor: UIColor.textLight)
}
```